# Is there no way to reliably work with slot content in Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuejs-slots

I am currently migrating a Vue 2 codebase to Vue 3.

```
<card>
    <template #default>
        <card-header>
            <title level="3">Header</title>
        </card-header>
        <card-body
            v-for="b in bodyCount"
            :key="'b' + b">
            Body {{ b }}
        </card-body>
        <card-footer
            v-for="f in footerCount"
            :key="'f' + f">
            <text>Footer {{ f }}</text>
        </card-footer>
    </template>
</card>
```

Card component has a render function which calls `this.$slots.default()`. However in Vue 3 this returns different content to what it did in Vue 2. So if I do `console.log(this.$slots.default())` - I get an array with 3 elements, [v-node with type: 'header', v-node with type: Symbol(Fragment), v-node with type: Symbol(Fragment)]

More specifically it does not identify card-footer/card-body as components but rather I see Symbol (Fragment) in the type. Card-header is actually fine because it is not in a v-for loop.

There is logic inside the render function of the card component which needs to know how many body/footer components it has. So I need to be able to tell the component types. Is this not possible in Vue 3? I can guess that this is related to the v-for here but I am not sure how to actually get the end result v-nodes. In this example I would have expected the array to contain the card-header + all card bodies + all card footers instead of 3 elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out - Fragments can be unwrapped through the children property on each element of the array. So v-for in this case results in a v-node which is a fragment but we can infer further content by looking at the children property.

Answer (score -1):

The design of your card component does not look meaningful to me. I suggest you to rethink it.

Here is the simple playground rendering slots

```js
const { createApp, h } = Vue;

const Card = {
  setup(props, { attrs, slots, emit, expose }) {
      return () => [           
          h('label', 'Card'),
          h('div', 'Slots:'),
          h('div', {}, slots.default()),
          h('div', {}, slots.header()),
          h('div', {}, slots.body()),
          h('div', {}, slots.footer())
      ]
  }
}

const App = { 
  components: { Card },
  data() {
    return {
    }  
  }
}
const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 2; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
label { font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<div id="app">
<card>
    <template #default>
       Default
        <card-header>
            <title level="3">Header</title>
        </card-header>
    </template>
    <template #header>
       Header
    </template>
    <template #body>
       Body
    </template>
    <template #footer>
       Footer
    </template>
</card>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
```

Pay attention to the warning. Vue does not render here `card-header`, since it  cannot resolve it.

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: card-header
If this is a native custom elemen
```

And why do you want to manipulate the `card-body`/`card-footer` items over `slots`, if you can just access the data directly over `bodyCount`?

If looks not reasonable for me.

```js
const { createApp, h } = Vue;

const CardHeader = {
    template: '<div class="card-header">card-header: <slot></slot></div>'
}
const CardBody = {
    template: '<div class="card-body">card-body: <slot></slot></div>'
}
const CardFooter = {
    template: '<div class="card-footer">card-footer: <slot></slot></div>'
}

const Card = {
  components: {
    CardHeader, CardBody, CardFooter
  },
  setup(props, { attrs, slots, emit, expose }) {
      //console.log(slots.default())
      return () => [           
          h('label', 'Card'),
          h('div', 'Slots:'),
          h('div', {}, slots.default()),
      ]
  }
}

const App = { 
  components: { Card, CardHeader, CardBody, CardFooter },
  data() {
    return {
      bodyCount: ['a','b'],
      footerCount: ['a','b']
    }  
  }
}
const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 2; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
label { font-weight: bold; }
.card-header, .card-body, .card-footer {
  border: 1px solid #F0F0F0;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
<card>
    <template #default>
        <card-header>
            <div level="3">Header</div>
        </card-header>
        bodyCount: {{bodyCount.length}}
        <card-body
            v-for="b in bodyCount"
            :key="'b' + b">
            Body {{ b }}
        </card-body>
        footerCount: {{footerCount.length}}
        <card-footer
            v-for="f in footerCount"
            :key="'f' + f">
            <text>Footer {{ f }}</text>
        </card-footer>
    </template>
</card>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```